# Find X and Y, iid, such that W=X-Y has uniform distribution on (-1,1). It is possible?

Tags: probability

It is possible to find two random variables X and Y, with X,Y independent and identically distributed, such that w = X-Y  has uniform distribution in (-1,1)? Why?

Answer (score 4):

No.  The characteristic function of $X-Y$ is $|\phi|^2$ where $\phi$ is the characteristic function of $X$, but the characteristic function of $U[-1,1]$ is  $\sin(at)/at$ (for some real value of $a$ unimportant here), which takes on negative values.

Comment: Thanks. i really understand. The idea is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

It is trivial to show that both $X,Y$ must have support on $[-1/2,1/2]$. Now let $f,F$ be the pdf and cdf of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

You need
$$
F_W(w)
 = \mathbb{P}[W \le w]
 = \mathbb{P}[X-Y \le w]
 = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \mathbb{I}_{x-y \le w} f(x) f(y) dxdy
$$
could you compute the integral? What should the LHS be equal to? Can you solve this?

Comment: You assume that pdf exists?  That is, you assume absolutely continuous random variables?

Comment: @GEdgar i would experiment that way to see if i can find one, and if i can - it will exist. If not, will think about it not being possible. OP asked without any serious effort, I have given a line of thought to try